# Is there a command choose where you want to start and stop parsing data in a text file?

Tags: python, string, parsing

Is there a command (line or string) to choose where you want to start and stop parsing data of x in a text file? Is there some sort of string command to read between specific parts of strings?

Let's say that the Textfile is:

```
[6-1-14] Data Record [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14]   x=4, y=5 [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14]   x=3, y=4 [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14] Data Stop [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14] Debug: Start [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14]   x=4, y=5 [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14] Debug: End [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14] Data Record [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14]   x=2, y=3 [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14]   x=1, y=2 [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14] Data Stop [9:55:00AM]
[6-3-14] Data Record [9:55:00AM]
[6-3-14]   x=0, y=1 [9:55:00AM]
[6-3-14] Data Stop [9:55:00AM]
```

Desired Output:
**All values to be stored in a list that are between Data Record and Data Stop. Values between Debug: Start and Debug: End should not be recorded.**

```
x =[4,3,2,1]
```

Motive for the code:
Store all values of x between the strings Data Record and Data Stop and nowhere else.

Comment: What "command"? What language? What context? This is wayyyyy too broad.

Comment: Python. Command as in some kind of predefined variable to search in the string. Something similar to 

line.strip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python you can do something like:

```
text = """  your text as above """
p1=0
output=""
while True:
    p2 = text.find("Data Record",p1)+11
    p3 = text.find("Data Stop", p1)
    if p2<0 or p3<0: break
    s = text[p2:p3]
    output +=s
    p1=p3+10

print output
```

which prints

```
[9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14]   x=4, y=5 [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14]   x=3, y=4 [9:55:00AM]
[6-1-14]  [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14]   x=2, y=3 [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14]   x=1, y=2 [9:55:00AM]
[6-2-14]  [9:55:00AM]
[6-3-14]   x=0, y=1 [9:55:00AM]
[6-3-14]
```

Which is the bit between the Record and Stop bits. You could then parse that?